# sftp command with '\' in username does not work

Tags: shell, quoting, sftp

The end server expects the username to come as Usertype\username@IPaddress in SFTP. For e.g. command is given as `stfp Admin\primary@10.10.10.10`. But it does not work.

Is there any other option using sftp?

Comment: Try it with two backslashes. `sftp Admin\\primary@10.10.10.10`

Answer (score 3):

The backslash is the so called `escape character` and needs to be escaped itself if it appears on the command line or on other places where escape characters are processed.

A username with such an unusual character inside may cause problems in various situations. Better try to avoid it.